# No Mapping exists from object type System.windows.controls.ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, authentication, sqlconnection

I am trying to create a login page that requires a student number, password and year.
I have created my database in SSMS and have linked it to my program like so:

```
    modulesInfo m1 = new modulesInfo();
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    //m1.Show();

    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = Tarisai; Initial Catalog = LoginDB; Integrated Security=SSPI ");
    try
    {

        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_Users WHERE Username = @Student_Number AND Password = @Password AND Year =@Year" ;


        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_Number", studentnumberBox.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", studentpasswordBox.Password);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", studentyearBox.SelectedItem);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 1)
        {
            m1.Show();
            this.Close();

        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {

        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

I am getting the **No Mapping exists from object type System.windows.controls.ComboBox** error and im not sure how to fix it.

I am assuming mu error is on this line `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", studentyearBox.SelectedItem);`because the error mentions a combobox
Thank you for your help

Comment: Selecteditem is of type object what is year? Int maybe? And what's itemssource of your combo? Maybe you want selectedvalue.

Comment: @Tarisai Gonah: How do you add items to or set the `ItemsSource` property of `studentyearBox`?